# How to hide a division on page load if the if condition is valid in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Typeofproperty, "1", new { @class = "Tproperty" })


<div id="residential" class="option">
    <h5>*Residental Project Name :</h5>
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName)
</div>
```

Js/jQuery:

```
$('input[class="Tproperty"]').$(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '2' || $(this).val() == '5' || $(this).val() == '8') {
        $('#Display').show();
        $('#residential').hide();
        $('#amen').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#Display').show();
        $('#residential').show();
        $('#amen').show();
    }
});
```

On page load I want the residential division tag to be hidden if the radio buttons 2,5 or 8 are checked. These radio buttons for type of property refers to the house, villa etc.

Comment: A fiddle will works..

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tpropval=$(".Tproperty").val();
    if (tpropval == '2' || tpropval == '5' || tpropval == '8') {
        $('#Display').show();
        $('#residential').hide();
        $('#amen').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#Display').show();
        $('#residential').show();
        $('#amen').show();

    }
});
```

Comment: The thing is this is the Edit page on which the radio buttons will populate according to the db values.I want to verify is the button checked is 2,5 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

Put Your login inside `.ready()` function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(condition == true)
    //show or hide div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this. There isnt any need to use jquery, you can easily use condition in your razor view and apply repspective class.

Classes to apply depending on condition

```
.display-none{display:none}
.display-block{display:block}
```

Below is code to apply class.

```
<div id="residential" class=@if(Model.Condition){<text>display-none</text>}
                                         else{<text>display-block</text>}>
                                >
                            <h5>*Residental Project Name :</h5>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName)
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('input:eq(0), input:eq(1), input:eq(5)').length==$('input:eq(0).Tproperty, input:eq(1).Tproperty, input:eq(5).Tproperty').length{
    $('#Display').show();
    $('#residential').hide();
    $('#amen').hide();
}
else {
    $('#Display').show();
    $('#residential').show();
    $('#amen').show();
}
```